# How to deal with integrals in the form of $\int x^m(a+bx^n)^p$?

Tags: calculus, integration

In the book I'm reading, it briefly explained how to evaluate integrals in the form $\int x^m(a+bx^n)^pdx$ where $m,n,p\in\mathbb{Q}$ :

> 1)If $p$ be a natural number then we expand $(a+bx^n)^p$ with
> binomial expansion and then integrate.
>
> 2)If $p$ is a negative integer then we use the substitution $x=t^k$ (
> $k$: $LCM$ of denominators  $m,n$)
>
> 3)If $\frac{m+1}n\in\mathbb{Z}$ then we use the substitution
> $a+bx^n=t^k$ ($k$: denominator of $p$ )
>
> 4)If $\frac{m+1}n+p\in\mathbb{Z}$ then we use the substitution
> $a+bx^n=x^n.t^k$ ($k$: denominator of $p$)

After that the book brings two examples:
$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]{x^2}}}dx\qquad\qquad\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}}$$

And for each one they wrote in the form of $\int x^m(a+bx^n)^pdx$ then decide which of these four cases it is and used the suitable  substitution for that.

I hadn't much experience in evaluating this form of integrals before. So can you please explain me the reason for these substitution ? And do you really follow these instructions every time you face these integrals? (I really hate doing some instructions blindly in math just because doing that lead to the correct answer).

Comment: Instead of blindly following instructions, you can learn to *derive* integration formulas. That way you make the instructions *your own*.

Comment: @LeeMosher I don't know how to start. should I start deriving formulas by the general form?

Comment: Like all mathematics, you start with the simplest cases. If you cannot do a case, move to a simpler one. If you can do a case, move to a harder one.

Comment: That's how you *build* experience that you do not yet have.

Comment: @LeeMosher Great Advice! thank you very much!

Comment: @Amirali: The idea is to transform something tat in principle looks awful into something that is familiar and simple.  the first suggested method for example gives you sums of integrals os the form $x^k$; the second would give you quotient of polynomials for which the method of partial fractions can be used; the other two allow to convert the problem to integrals where eventiually a trigonometric substitition maybe used. Again, there are general methods that were developed by years of experienced. A starting point if you will.

Comment: @Amirali:  hope that make it a requirement to add a justification for downvotes. Your question is not bad at all. That type of integrals had good pedigree and were studied by Chebyshev and Ostogradsky. Many old soviet books dedicated a chapter to such integrals and there are some interesting things about them, specially the cases that are not "solvable".

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you very much for the kind words! I think people on MSE like to see some problems to solve rather than these type of questions.